# How to fix " Access Denied to perform this action: View user permissions on a resource" while publishing my custom vscode extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have written a vs-code extension and I packaged it successfully, but I  had beaten by an error while publishing it.

$ vsce publish
...
...
 Access Denied: Srikanth Bhamidipalli needs the following permission(s) on the resource /Srikanth to perform this action: View user permissions on a resource

I expect it should publish.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me when the name of my publisher didn't match the publisher in my `package.json` file.

I created my publisher online using my web browser and the publisher ID was PetrHudeek. With `vsce`, I logged in using my personal access token to an account with that publisher, but my `package.json` file had `hudecekpetr` as the publisher.

Make sure that the value of the key `publisher` in your package.json matches your publisher ID online (the string after `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/` in the URL).

Comment: I actually had to go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/ where it prompted me to create a publisher, I didn't see this in the VSCode documentation. Once I created a publisher with a matching ID, everything worked as expected. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Use the Publisher ID, lower case string inside the round brackets, neither "User Id" (UUID prompt when you hover over the email address) nor the Publisher Name.